# how to use variables in include files

Tags: php

Is it possible to include files with a variable inside of `include`?

See this example:

```
$randfilescnt = rand(1,$filecount);

include('./quizes/Arrow/quiz'+ $randfilescnt +'.php');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That would work if you were using the right concatenator. `+` is for javascript, `.` is for PHP.

Comment: @rajdevkumar are the javascript, html and css tags relevant to the question? If not, please remove them

Comment: @aynber Thanks it works <3

Comment: @LinkinTED removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "." for string concat in php

```
 $randfilescnt = rand(1,$filecount);

    include('./quizes/Arrow/quiz'.$randfilescnt.'.php');
```

Comment: thanks it works <3

Comment: welcome. please mark as fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this way :

```
$randfilescnt = rand(1,$filecount);
include("./quizes/Arrow/quiz".$randfilescnt.".php");
```

Comment: it works thanks <3

Comment: @rajdevkumar You are meant to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @TNU ? i did n´t understand